# Non-resolvable import POM when specifying SNAPSHOT version

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am trying to build a maven project that declares a dependency management section where a pom dependency has a SNAPSHOT version. However it refuses to build unless I set a non-SNAPSHOT version instead.

My settings.xml defines this mirror and it contains all the snapshot versions I need:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>public</id>
    <url>http://repoHost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Here is what I believe to be the relevant sections of the pom:

```
<properties>
  <myArtifactId.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</myArtifactId.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>myParentArtifactId</artifactId>
      <version>${myParentArtifactId.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>subproject1</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>subproject2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>subproject3</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>subproject4</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>subproject5</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>subproject6</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>mySnapshots</id>
    <url>http://repoHost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
  <repository>
    <id>myReleases</id>
    <url>http://repoHost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/my-releases</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Here is the error I see, with line and column references updated to match the pom snippet above:

```
PS > mvn -U -X -e clean
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\dev\java\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre
Default locale: sv_SE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Using mirror public (http://repoHost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/) for central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project exampleGroupId:ptexample:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata myGroupId:myParentArtifactId:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\cb2\.m2\repository)
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact myGroupId:myParentArtifactId:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ line 7, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject1:jar is missing. @ line 18, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject2:jar is missing. @ line 22, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject3:jar is missing. @ line 26, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject4:jar is missing. @ line 30, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject5:jar is missing. @ line 34, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject6:jar is missing. @ line 38, column 19
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact myGroupId:myParentArtifactId:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ line 7, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject1:jar is missing. @ line 18, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject2:jar is missing. @ line 22, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject3:jar is missing. @ line 26, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject4:jar is missing. @ line 30, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject5:jar is missing. @ line 34, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject6:jar is missing. @ line 38, column 19

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:422)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project exampleGroupId:ptexample:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\projects\bitbucket\EW\pt-example\pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact myGroupId:myParentArtifactId:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ line 7, column 21 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact myGroupId:myParentArtifactId:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:197)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1192)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:455)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:421)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:620)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:411)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact myGroupId:myParentArtifactId:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:193)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact myGroupId:myParentArtifactId:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434)
        ... 27 more
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject1:jar is missing. @ line 18, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject2:jar is missing. @ line 22, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject3:jar is missing. @ line 26, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject4:jar is missing. @ line 30, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject5:jar is missing. @ line 34, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for myGroupId:subproject6:jar is missing. @ line 38, column 19
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

The links in the output did provide some clues but I was unable to fix the problem anyway.

I can get it to work if I just update to use a specific version:

```
<properties>
  <myArtifactId.version>1.0.0</myArtifactId.version>
</properties>
```

But eliminating the referende to the myParentArtifactId dependency and specify SNAPSHOT versions on all the specified dependencies also fails with the initial "Could not find artifact"-error, like the one for "myGroupId:myParentArtifactId" above.

I can see the SNAPSHOT versions when browsing the repository that I see that Maven is using. The question is why does it not find the snapshots that are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And while formulating this question I actually managed to find an answer to it:

I added a build profile to my settings.xml that defines where to look for snapshots:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>development-build</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>      
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>snaps</id>
        <url>http://repoHost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

And now everything works as expected.

"Rubber-ducking" is awesome! :-)

Comment: This is the wrong solution. You have to change the configuration of your Nexus to correctly handle the SNAPSHOT repository into the public group instead.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise! I will look into that. What led me to only look for a client side solution was that I was the only one having this problem. Until yesterday I was unable to reproduce the error on any other machine. Then I discovered that by wiping the local Maven cache the error would appear on any machine without this extra repo config. So something could very well have changed on the Nexus server some time ago before I started working here (I'm fairly new at this place). Thanks again for the tip!